# Error running Jquery within Visual studio code

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am  new with jquery and trying to execute a basic example. Actually I am using Visual code for programming. This is my code:

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
      var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
      var text = document.getElementById("text");
      if (checkBox.checked == true) {
        text.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        text.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>
  Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">
  <p id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>
</body>
```

angular.jason file :

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.scss",
  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
  "./node_modules/simpl-theme-bootstrap/dist/js/simpl-theme-bootstrap.bundle.js"
]
```

Error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):1)

I have moved the function to the bottom of the body but did not solve the problem. Any Idea/Hint please ?

Comment: The code in your snippet appears to be working absolutely fine. Ensure that the location where you've defined `myFunction()` is within scope of the `onclick` attribute (ie. global)

Comment: put the whole bunch of your script before the close tag of body </body>

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you for your comment.I think the problem with the scope too. Please could you tell me where is the scope of  'onclick'? the function should be in the header isnt it ?

Comment: @UllasHunka  thank you but did not work

Comment: the same code works here, I think there is problem with my  configuration in Visual Studio code

Comment: VS Code is merely the IDE where you write the code. The code is actually _executed_ within the web browser. So it's unlikely to be an issue with the config of VS Code. In reality is this function contained within a separate .js file, or within your HTML page (like in your snippet above, which works perfectly)?

Comment: The is pure JavaScript (no JQuery). You can test by creating a simple html file. Looks like you are referring to https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_display_checkbox_text

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox. Try using onchange instead of onclick. Also, try with addEventListener